# How to make pivot query that returns no rows return null instead. (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that is structured like this:

```
SELECT
                        "result1"                   
                    ,   "result2" 
                    ,   "result3" 

FROM
(    
    SELECT number, position
    FROM values val
    FULL JOIN values2 val2 ON val.id = val2.id
    WHERE val.code = 'example'
    AND val.number IS NOT NULL
)
PIVOT
(
  MAX(number)
  FOR position IN(
    1  AS "result1",
    2  AS "result2",
    3  AS "result3"
  )
);
```

For the case of it returning no values, I want it to return null-values instead of a empty row.

How would I achieve this? I was not able to make commonly suggested solutions work, because of the pivot.

E:

The result I get:

No row returned:

[image]

The result I want:

One row returned with null values

[image]

Comment: Can you provide test data?

Comment: If your table has no rows with code `example` then this query returns one row containing 3 null values: [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=64300e85b67293eb564417fd75e8abbc). What do you mean by: return null-values instead of a empty row?

Comment: If you don't want this row just add `where "result1" is not null or "result2" is not null or "result3" is not null` after pivot.

Comment: This sadly doesn't happen with my code. I get a completely empty row (ie no result at all) instead of one row containing 3 null values. Is there a way to guarantee this to happen? Replicating the structure with test data would be a rather complex undertaking.

Comment: I need this row, my problem is nothing being returned at all (zero rows)

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is the difference between an "empty row" and a row where all the columns have `NULL` values?

Comment: I provided actual and desired results in my post now. The difference in this case is needed, because of how code that I do not have access to expects the result.

Comment: You provided results, but not the original data that does or should give you those results. You are using a full outer join; as far as I can see you'll get the result you want now (e.g. if both tables are empty). It would be helpful if you used valid column names too - I assume you've translated those for us, but as those are not legal it's harder to interpret.

Comment: Since this doesn't seem to be reproducible with what you have in the question, and you've implied you've simplified it, I think you're focusing on the wrong thing. Rather than trying to make pivot do what you want, modify your real subquery to make sure that always returns at least one row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with the `PIVOT` it is with the sub-query before the `PIVOT` and your question can be reduced to:

> How can I get the query (renaming your identifiers to have legal values):
>
> ```sql
> SELECT num,
>        position
> FROM   values1 val
>        FULL OUTER JOIN values2 val2
>        ON val.id = val2.id
> WHERE  val.code = 'example'
> AND    val.num IS NOT NULL
> ```
>
> to always return at least one row?

If you have the test data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE values1 ( id, code, num ) AS
SELECT 1, 'example',     NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'not_example', 1    FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE values2 ( id, position ) AS
SELECT 1, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 3 FROM DUAL;
```

Then there is no row that will match the filter conditions in your `WHERE` clause and there will be zero rows to `PIVOT` so the query will always return zero rows. In this case then you can use `UNION ALL` to add a row:

```sql
SELECT num,
       position
FROM   values1 val
       FULL OUTER JOIN values2 val2
       ON val.id = val2.id
WHERE  val.code = 'example'
AND    val.num IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,
       NULL
FROM   DUAL
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM   value1
  WHERE  code = 'example'
  AND    num IS NOT NULL
)
```

Which will output:

> ```
>  NUM | POSITION
> ---: | -------:
> null |     null
> ```

And then wrapped with the pivot:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
(    
  SELECT num,
         position
  FROM   values1 val
         FULL OUTER JOIN values2 val2
         ON val.id = val2.id
  WHERE  val.code = 'example'
  AND    val.num IS NOT NULL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL,
         NULL
  FROM   DUAL
  WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM   values1
    WHERE  code = 'example'
    AND    num IS NOT NULL
  )
)
PIVOT ( MAX(num) FOR position IN (
  1  AS "result1",
  2  AS "result2",
  3  AS "result3"
));
```

Outputs:

> ```
> result1 | result2 | result3
> ------: | ------: | ------:
>    null |    null |    null
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c5d8f4ffc5e6473136e92616faf9239a)*

Comment: The query in your fiddle [returns a row](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7c8f74cb4c64f05dd823058f31aa11a0) for an empty set, without this union. No matter if this is pivot or simple aggregate: `select max(dummy) from (select * from dual where 1=0)`.

Comment: @PonderStibbons Good catch (but then the OP's question doesn't really make sense). However, if they are also returning another column (such as `id`) then it will return zero rows [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=39ad7658df1839b2b5ab0d10fa068565).

Comment: Because it finds no `id` for grouping in this case. At least this explains something.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by creating a view out of this query and calling the view like this:

```
SELECT                   NVL(MIN(result1), null)                
                    ,    NVL(MIN(result2), null)    
                    ,    NVL(MIN(result3), null)    
FROM schema.view;
```